# Radio button calculator with nested if Stateme

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to create a pricing calculator that takes all of the checked radio buttons and pushes them into an array where it is added in the end. However, I would like to have one of the radio buttons take the attribute of the first radio button and multiply it by its own value.

I tried nesting an if statement inside of another if statement but it will only seem to add the values of the first if statement and ignore the second.

```js
$(".w-radio").change(function() {
  var totalPrice = 0,
    values = [];

  $("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      if ($(this).is('[name="catering"]')) {
        var cateringFunc = (
          $(this).val() * $('[name="gastronomy"]').attr("add-value")
        ).toString();
        values.push($(this).val());
      }
      values.push($(this).val());
      totalPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });

  $("#priceTotal span").text(totalPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">

  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="0" add-value="10">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" add-value="10">550<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" add-value="10">550<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" add-value="10">550<BR>
</label>
<br>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="0">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
</label>
<br>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="0">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="40">40<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="45">45<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="60">60<BR>
</label>

<div class="hack42-45-added-value-row">

  <div id="priceTotal">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the selector `input[type=radio]:checked` instead of the `if` statement to test if it's checked.

Comment: You're setting `cateringFunc` but never doing anything with it.

Comment: `$('[name="gastronomy"]').val()` is the value of the first gastronomy button. Do you want the one that's checked?

Comment: What is the `values` array for? You push onto it, but never use the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the condition is true you should use `cateringFunc` instead of `$(this).val()` when pushing into the `values` array and adding to `totalPrice`.

I assume you only want to get the added value from the selected radio button, so I added `:checked` to the selector. Then you also need to provide a default value if none of the `gastronomy` buttons are checked.

You shouldn't make up new attributes like `add-value`. If you need custom attributes, use `data-XXX`. These can be accessed using the jQuery `.data()` method.

```js
$(".w-radio").change(function() {
  var totalPrice = 0,
    values = [];

  $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[name="catering"]')) {
      var cateringFunc = (
        $(this).val() * ($('[name="gastronomy"]:checked').data("add-value") || 0)
      );
      values.push(cateringFunc.toString());
      totalPrice += cateringFunc;
    }
    values.push($(this).val());
    totalPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  $("#priceTotal span").text(totalPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="0" data-add-value="10">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" data-add-value="10">550<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" data-add-value="10">550<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="gastronomy" value="550" data-add-value="10">550<BR>
</label>
<br>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="0">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="venue" value="10500">10500<BR>
</label>
<br>
<label class="hack43-radio-group w-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="0">0<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="40">40<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="45">45<BR>
  <input type="radio" name="catering" value="60">60<BR>
</label>

<div class="hack42-45-added-value-row">

  <div id="priceTotal">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```